# How to Bypass Usb Device access pop up android?

Tags: java, android, usb

I have an app on a tablet android 8.1 that opens when i attach a usb device and is setted by home default.

The first time i attach the usb  , android asks me if i can open app when the usb device is connected and i apply it by default , the device work .

But everytime i reboot the device and the app opens , it show me the pop up again.
i really need to bypass this fact because this fact is not accettable for the user experience.

The action that i made are:

- install the app
- attach the usb device
- app opens
- this pop up appear :

[image]

-i click on Use by default

-the usb device work

-reboot device

-the pop up returns

i tried to following these guides but none of them worked for me , expecially because i'm not experienced enough with java:
-[USB device access pop-up suppression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388914/usb-device-access-pop-up-suppression)

-[How to handle App permission pop ups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977669/how-to-handle-app-permission-pop-ups-system-popups-like-device-location-contact)

-[how to prevent android from getting popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63933328/how-to-prevent-android-from-getting-popup-as-open-app-when-this-usb-device-is-co)

-[Remember USB connection, but don't launch the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058911/remember-usb-connection-but-dont-launch-the-application)

my manifest :

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.liliumduva">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I really need help i'm really stuck with this , thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

To bypass this i created a boot receiver java class that close the app on device reboot.
Then with the help of tasker i made it click on ok on the pop up and then i make the application launch always with tasker.
if you want further information i will share code .